# "Null check operator used on a null value" when calling a Provider at dispose()

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider, google-maps-flutter

I have a "Null check operator used on a null value" error after leaving the page with `Navigator.pop(context)`.
The stack says the error is here

```
@override
  void dispose() {
    final googleMapsNotifier =
        Provider.of<GoogleMapsNotifier>(context, listen: false); // !!!THIS LINE CAUSES THE ERROR
     googleMapsNotifier.dispose();
    locationSubscription.cancel();
    boundsSubscription.cancel();
    addressSearchController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
```

Here is the Class file that this Provider calls

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:dev/model/mapsModels/geometry.dart';
import 'package:dev/model/mapsModels/location.dart';
import 'package:dev/model/mapsModels/place.dart';
import 'package:dev/model/mapsModels/place_search.dart';
import 'package:dev/services/mapsServices/geolocator_service.dart';
import 'package:dev/services/mapsServices/places_service.dart';
import 'package:dev/services/marker_service.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';
import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';
import 'package:rxdart/rxdart.dart';

class GoogleMapsNotifier with ChangeNotifier {
  final geolocatorService = GeolocatorService();
  final placesService = PlacesService();
  final markerService = MarkerService();

  Position? currentLocation;
  List<PlaceSearch> searchResults = [];
  StreamController<Place> selectedLocation = BehaviorSubject<Place>();
  StreamController<LatLngBounds> bounds = BehaviorSubject<LatLngBounds>();
  late Place selectedLocationStatic;
  List<Marker> markers = <Marker>[];

  GoogleMapsNotifier() {
    setCurrentLocation();
  }

  setCurrentLocation() async {
    currentLocation = await geolocatorService.determinePosition();
    selectedLocationStatic = Place(
        geometry: Geometry(
          location: Location(
              lat: currentLocation!.latitude, lng: currentLocation!.longitude),
        ),
        name: '',
        vicinity: '');
    notifyListeners();
  }

  searchPlaces(String searchTerm) async {
    searchResults = await placesService.getAutocomplete(searchTerm);
    notifyListeners();
  }

  setSelectedLocation(String placeId) async {
    var sLocation = await placesService.getPlace(placeId);
    selectedLocation.add(sLocation);
    selectedLocationStatic = sLocation;
    searchResults = [];
    markers = [];
    var newMarker = markerService.createMarkerFromPlace(sLocation);
    markers.add(newMarker);
    var _bounds = markerService.bounds(Set<Marker>.of(markers));
    bounds.add(_bounds as LatLngBounds);
    notifyListeners();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
 
      selectedLocation.close();
    

    super.dispose();
  }
}
```

At the same time, the app does NOT crush and it all works fine after this error.
If I remove this line inside `dispose()`, the error disappears.
I tried this and it did not help

> Open your terminal and run flutter channel stable. Then run flutter
> upgrade. After that run, flutter pub cache repair to reinstall the
> packages in your system cache. Then Just clean the build folder using
> flutter clean.

Flutter Doctor shows no issues.
Any ideas what can it be?
Thanks in advance.

UPD:
I found out that even if `class GoogleMapsNotifier` is absolutely empty, the error remains.
So its the call itself

```
final googleMapsNotifier = Provider.of<GoogleMapsNotifier>(context, listen: false);
```

if its located in `dispose()` is causing the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it simple.
As the Stream and its `dispose()` function are located in separate class accessed with Provider, I took a call to it outside the `dispose()` of the `StatefulWidget` and placed it to the `onTap` of a button that pops the context.

```
onTap: () {
      Provider.of<GoogleMapsNotifier>(context, listen: false).dispose();             
      Navigator.pop(context);
          },
```

Now the error has gone.